# How to generate multiple new columns through applying function by row in pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to run `apply` in `pandas.DataFrame` so that a function would run through the whole table, taking a few column fields as input, and generate multiple new fields at the same time, and once the scan is done, the new fields could form extra multiple new columns.

Conceptually the following describes what I need: to apply a function `f` to the DataFrame column-wise to generate multiple new columns *at the same time*:

```
f :: field1, field2, field3, ... -> newfield1, newfield2,...
```

when I apply this function to the DataFrame, it gives me

```
f' :: column1, column2, column3, ... -> newcolumn1, newcolumn2, ...
```

Here is an example:

```
>>> df
   denominator  numerator
0            3         10
1            5         12
2            7         14
```

I would like to create two more columns, `quotient` and `remainder`.

In this particular example I could run `//` and `%` separately because it is trivial but it is not the preferred because I can technically get both quotient and remainder at the same time. In some real world cases, getting them at the same time is more efficient.

The following is what I came up with but I don't know if it is the most pythonic way of doing it. How `df.apply` turns a sequence of row-based `pd.Series` into columns is also not clear to me.

```
>>> def rundivmod(n, d):
...   q, r = divmod(n, d)
...   return {'quotient': q, 'remainder': r}
>>> pd.merge(df, df.apply(lambda row: pd.Series(rundivmod(row.numerator, row.denominator)), axis=1), left_index=True, right_index=True)
   denominator  numerator  quotient  remainder
0            3         10         3          1
1            5         12         2          2
2            7         14         2          0
```

EDIT: removed my other method to generate `quotient` and `remainder` separately as they are misleading in this case.

Comment: `df['quotient'], df['remainder'] = df['numerator']//df['denominator'], df['numerator'] % df['denominator']`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function:

```
def rundivmod(n, d):
    return divmod(n, d)
```

Code:

```
out = df.apply(lambda x: rundivmod(x['numerator'], x['denominator']) ,1).apply(pd.Series)
out.columns = ['quotient', 'remainder']
df = pd.concat([df, out], 1)
```

Output:

```
    denominator numerator   quotient    remainder
0   3             10          3          1
1   5             12          2          2
2   7             14          2          0
```

Comment: I could do this but that's not the point. I will delete my option 1)

Comment: the point is to run a function that takes n columns and returns m-tuple and add the m-tuple to the data frame as m columns.

Comment: If the motive for getting both the quotient and remainder at the same time is performance, this answer should be much faster than using any kind of `.apply` since it uses vectorized operations.

Answer (score 1):

In general you should avoid `apply` if possible, many operations can be done without iterating over the rows. But if for some reason you must, you can create a function that returns a Series after acting on the rows and then `concat` that back.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'data': [2,3,4,5]})
```

Raises 'data' to multiple powers<sup>1</sup>

```
def apply_pow(row, N):
    return pd.Series(row['data']**np.array(range(N)),
                     index=[f'power_{i}' for i in range(N)],  # become col names
                     )

pd.concat([df, df.apply(apply_pow, N=3, axis=1)], axis=1)
#   data  power_0  power_1  power_2
#0     2        1        2        4
#1     3        1        3        9
#2     4        1        4       16
#3     5        1        5       25
```

---

<sup>1</sup>should be vectorized using `np.vander(df['data'], N=3, increasing=True)`